# How to query, by data range, a composite column in Cassandra with TimeUUID as the first component?

Tags: date, dynamic, cassandra, composite

1) Inserting a column

```
DynamicComposite dc = new DynamicComposite();
dc.add(0,TimeUUIDUtils.getUniqueTimeUUIDinMillis());
```

2) Trying to query the column between given time range using a SliceQuery

```
UUID afterUUID = TimeUUID.getTimeUUID((new Date (2012, 7, 17, 24, 0).getTime())); 
    UUID beforeUUID = TimeUUID.getTimeUUID((new Date (2012, 7, 20, 24, 0).getTime())); 
    startRange.add(0, afterUUID);
    endRange.addComponent(0,beforeUUID, UUIDSerializer.get(), "TimeUUIDType", AbstractComposite.ComponentEquality.GREATER_THAN_EQUAL);
```

executing the code on 7/19 so the column should match but nothing.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I am using a Long with just a System.currentTimeMillis() for now. Till I find a problem to the original solution.

Answer (score 0):

Cassandra is using UTC as `System.currentTimeInMillis()` also does. When querying with time in UTC, your queries should work.